# Link button and Bootstrap glyphicons styling issue

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

The issue I have that when I use LinkButton in dropdown-menu the icon and LinkButton text are showed in tow separate lines.

[image: OUTPUT]

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li>
    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#">Hi,
      <asp:Label ID="lbllname" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
      <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul style="margin: 25px 15px 0 0;" role="menu" class="dropdown-setting dropdown-menu bg-amber">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="entypo-user"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;My Profile</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="entypo-vcard"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Account Setting</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="entypo-lifebuoy"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Help</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="icon-upload"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <asp:LinkButton ID="btnlogout" OnClick="btnlogout_Click" runat="server">Log out</asp:LinkButton></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Link button rendered in the browser like below**

```
<li>
<a href="#">
<span class="icon-upload"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</a><a id="btnlogout" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$btnlogout','')">Log out</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give this as a CSS Fix:

```
.navbar-right li {white-space: nowrap;}
```

It is caused because of your improper usage of `&nbsp;`, which can be fixed by forcing the browser to render the text in a single line, using the `nowrap`.

Another issue is you have a **nested `<a>`** tag. This shouldn't happen. Please change the markup this way:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnlogout" OnClick="btnlogout_Click" runat="server">
    <span class="icon-upload"></span> Log out
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: No luck i even removed &nbsp; nothing changes

Comment: @Ayman Sorry, I just changed the CSS a little bit. Remove the `a` from it. Check now?

Comment: Np, i still have the issue

Comment: @Ayman Inspect the LI, screenshot the full Inspect Screen with all the styles over on the right, with HTML. Update the rendered HTML as well.

Comment: Got it. You shouldn't have a wrapping `<a>`.